# Synthesisable Fixed/Floating points in VHDL's IEEE Library

Tags: vhdl, ieee-754, fixed-point, synthesis, ieee

I'm creating a VHDL project (Xilinx ISE for Spartan-6) that will be required to use decimal "real-style" numbers in either fixed/floating point (I'm hoping fixed point will be sufficient).

Being quite new to VHDL, I found out the hard way that the non-constant `real` types are not supported for synthesis, so I set about searching for a IP core or library to redress this.

So far I've found 3 options;

1) A [floating point IP core](http://www.xilinx.com/products/intellectual-property/floating_pt.html#documentation) provided by Xilinx

2) A downloadable "ieee_proposed" library written by a David Bishop [found here](http://www.eda.org/fphdl/)

3) After spending a fair while attempting to work out how to "create" a new library with David Bishops files in, I took a quick look through the default `IEEE` library and saw it contains `ieee.fixed_generic_pkg` and `ieee.fixed_pkg` packages.

My question is - of the two libraries - which one would be sensible to use? Is one adapted for synthesis and one not, or one older than the other? And then if floating point is provided, is there any real point to the floating point IP core provided by Xilinx?

I've trawled through many [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23501261/adding-library-to-vhdl-project) of people attempting to add the `ieee_proposed` libraries, but none seem to have referenced the fact they they already seem to exist in the existing `IEEE`.

Thanks very much for any help!

============UPDATE (Essentially my own efforts to resolve)==================

I can't actually use the `ieee.fixed_pkg` - and attempting to do so gives me the error `Cannot find <fixed_pkg> in library <ieee>`.

After finding the ieee library at C:\Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\ISE\vhdl\xst\nt I've found that the `fixed_pkg` actually resides in ieee_proposed. However, this still throws up the same errors!

Comment: Turn on VHDL-2008 compilation : the ieee_proposed packages moved into the ieee library eight years ago...

Comment: Using ISE I have set the project to use 200X vhdl if thats what it means - however it hasn't helped. Is that turning on VHDL-2008 compilation or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Also would appreciate feedback for the -1 vote if thats possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dumb question, but when you downloaded the **ieee_proposed** did you also remember to compile it?

edit: And also remember to map the library to you simulation as well. Maybe you did all this already but these are the mistakes I make often.

Comment: When you say compile...how should I have done that? I added it as a "new library" and attempted to run it...

Comment: Sorry, I do not know the details of this SW, but basically when you downloaded the ieee_proposed, it became "part of your own code". So the compiler has no predefined knowledge about it and you have to compile it alongside with your own code. And also remember to add the **library ieee_proposed;** into you code! I think the SW manual will be more helpful here.

Answer (score 2):

I've been battling with the same problems for days.
The way I solved it is:
1. Add fixed_float_types_c, fixed_pkg_c and float_pkg_c vhdl files to project.
2. Declare them as belonging to work library (Properties in Quartus files window)
3. Compile project and call library using:
Library work;
use work.fixed_pkg.all;

To my annoyance, they don't come up in the nice red writing I want them to but it works!